# .Net Core IFormFile convert to hexadecimal

Tags: asp.net-core, hex, typeconverter, iformfile

I have a project in Asp Net Core 3.1. I want to convert the downloaded mp3 files (of the IFormFile type) to hexadecimal.

What is the best way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

For converting IFormFile to hexadecimal, first IFormFile to byte array conversion is needed. Later, It can easily be converted to a hexadecimal string.

**Code:**

```
public async Task FileToHexaConversion(IFormFile file)
{
    await using var memoryStream = new MemoryStream();
    await file.CopyToAsync(memoryStream);
    var byteArray = memoryStream.ToArray(); //Byte Array Conversion

    string hexString = BitConverter.ToString(byteArray); //Hexadecimal String Conversion 

    Console.WriteLine(hexString.Replace('-', ' '));
}
```

***Note: Here, I replaced the hyphen separator with space.***